# Issue with uploading multiple files to rails per project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, shrine

I am building a project management application and I am using shrine to do file uploads. I got it working with only having one attachment per project, but now I want to set it up so that I can upload multiple files for any given project. Here is how I have it set up.

[GIST File](https://gist.github.com/spacerobotTR/9c1713b6831cda673a8834789c74a7f5)

What I want to do is upload files via shrine on the projects/show page, and associate uploads with both a user and project. Then just display href links to the files within the projects/show page above the uploader.

The form loads without errors but when I submit I get the following error:

[image]

Any thoughts or ideas are appreciated!

Comment: See the "Multiple Files" Shrine guide for tips on creating multiple file uploads: http://shrinerb.com/rdoc/files/doc/multiple_files_md.html. TL;DR use ActiveRecord's nested attributes, which is a common strategy for implementing any dynamic one-to-many associations.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at this.